# Check a line is exist in a text file or not in cmd

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

```
@echo off
set doit=false
if exist findstr /n . lla.txt | findstr ^j: set doit=true
if "%doit%"=="true" (
echo found
) else (
echo doelse
)
```

hi every one
i want to check lines in a text file
for example if line3 is exist in my text file then echo found
if not then echo doelse

whats my problem ?

Comment: Your problem is you are mixing commands together.  That is not the proper syntax for the `IF`, `FINDSTR`, and you can't do that `SET` after the 2nd `FINDSTR` like that.  I would advise you read the help for each command and adjust accordingly.

Comment: There's lots of [similar questions on SO]( https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bbatch-file%5DFind+line+of+text+in+file), did you bother to search for and study any of them?

Answer (score 0):

To see if `lla.txt` has at least `3` lines replace `j` with `3` and use this type of structure:

```bat
@Echo Off
(
    FindStr /N "^" "lla.txt" | FindStr "^j:" > Nul
) && (
    Echo Line Found
) || (
    Echo Line Not Found
)

Pause
```

This uses conditional execution, whereby:

- `&&` essentially means if the previous command/block was
  successful.
  *(returned a `0` `%ErrorLevel%`)*
- `||` essentially means if the previous command/block was
  unsuccessful.
  *(returned a non `0` `%ErrorLevel%`)*

---

If `lla.txt` cannot be found the first `FindStr` will output an error and carry out the commands within your `Line Not Found` parentheses.

If that's what you want then you can supress the error message by sending the `STDERR` output to a `NUL` device like this:

```bat
@Echo Off
(
    FindStr /N "^" "lla.txt" 2> Nul | FindStr "^j:" > Nul
) && (
    Echo Found
) || (
    Echo Line Not Found
)

Pause
```

If you want to do something different in those cases you should verify the source files existence first:

This uses an `If`/`Else` structure:

```bat
@Echo Off
If Exist "lla.txt" (
    (
        FindStr /N "^" "lla.txt" | FindStr "^j:" > Nul
    ) && (
        Echo Found
    ) || (
        Echo DoElse
    )
) Else (
    Echo No source file
)

Pause
```

This uses an `If`, `Echo`es a message for `3` seconds and `Exit`s

```bat
@Echo Off
If Not Exist "lla.txt" (
    Echo No source file
    Timeout /T 3 > Nul
    Exit /B
)

(
    FindStr /N "^" "lla.txt" | FindStr "^j:" > Nul
) && (
    Echo Line Found
) || (
    Echo Line Not Found
)

Pause
```